# Google Analytics for Windows Forms applications?

Tags: winforms, google-analytics

I need to track usage statistics (such as which features are mostly used etc.) for my Windows Forms app that communicates with a WCF Service. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this using Google analytics? Also what is the best way to implement this, from the client app or the WCF service or both?

Comment: Let me also know if you get the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send data directly to Google Analytics using the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol).

The requests are sent via HTTP, so in terms of whether you should send it from the client or the server or both, the choice is yours. Do whatever is easiest.

Comment: full sample in C# ?